# Angular show error 405 Method Not Allowed when set Authorization header

Tags: angularjs, api, cors, slim, restangular

I am using SLIM Framework (PHP) for Backend and Angular 1 for Frontend.

All APIs work fine until I set Authorization header when user logged in app.

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = token; // Token isvalid

// or

Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': token });
```

I got the error `405 Method Not Allowed (OPTIONS method)`. This error from my local, when I deploy Frontend to server, it works fine.

Should I fix on Frontend or Backend? And please help me how to fix it?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

OPTIONS is [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) preflight request. You need to enable CORS support. One way to do it is to use [CORS middleware](https://github.com/tuupola/cors-middleware).

Answer (score 0):

i do not know if any body still interested in this topic 
but i am going to tell you my approach
i added **CORS** Options to web config file in my api project and then add 
***[HttpOptions]*** attribute to my api method and then it started working 
i do not know if it is the right answer or not but until i find the better solution i am going to user this approach